# saving into a file in c

Tags: c, file, save, file-not-found

the scope of this function is to get inputs and save into a file . simple right ? but i cannot find the file after i input whith the console . please help me !

```
void addpassenger()
{
    int size = sizeof(struct passenger);
    struct passenger newPassenger;

    printf("Name: ");
    gets(newPassenger.name);

    printf("Surname: ");
    gets(newPassenger.surname);

    printf("ID card No: ");
    gets(newPassenger.idCard);

    printf("Nationality: ");
    gets(newPassenger.Nationality);

    printf("Telephone/Mobile: ");
    scanf("%d",&newPassenger.phone);

    FILE *pt =fopen("passenger.dat","a");
    fwrite(&newPassenger,size,1,pt);
    fclose(pt);

}
```

Comment: usually your working directory isn't where your executable is. best is to explicitly to set it or you just look where it is.

Comment: Since you give only the filename (and not a full path), the file will be in the [*current working directory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of the executable. Typically this is where you ran it from.

Answer (score -1):

fwrite - second and third arguments you have passed are wrong ..

Second Argument is  size -  Size in bytes of each element to be written.
size_t is an unsigned integral type.

Third argument is count - Number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.
size_t is an unsigned integral type

So your arguments should be

```
fwrite(&newPassenger,sizeof(int),size,pt);
```